# Debugging R closures

Tags: r, debugging, nested-function

To [debug](http://www.biostat.jhsph.edu/~rpeng/docs/R-debug-tools.pdf) a function `foo` in a file `foo.R`

```
foo <- function() {
    a <- c(2, 3)
}
```

one can write a "driver" file

```
source("foo.R")
debug(f)
f()
```

This can trivially be extended for many such functions in the same scope.

Debugging a function `bar()` inside the body of `foo` is a bit tedious

```
foo <- function() {
    bar <- function() {
        a <- c(2, 3)
    }
    bar()
}
```

one can start from the same driver file (a test file, in practice), load `bar()` without actually running it, type `debug(bar)` at the debug prompt, and then run `bar()`. I'm wondering if there is a better way for multiple closures.

Is there a way to specify in the driver/test file that I want to debug the inner function `bar`, something along the lines of `debug(foo::bar)`?

Does R provide a standard syntax to refer to inner functions (aka nested functions, aka closures, etc.)?

Related questions:

- [Advanced debugging functionality in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19454703/9295807)

Comment: Good question, but I think the answer is no. But if anything can do it maybe `trace()` is a good place to look. You also might want to look into something like `setBreakpoint()` but that uses line number rather than function names.

Comment: Just continuing the trace idea -- something like this "works": `trace(foo, quote(debug(bar)), at=3)` but you have to set the `at=` to some point after the function is defined and before it's called so that's not cool.

Answer (score 0):

You can just put a `browser()` at a point you want a debugger to be evoked:

```
foo <- function() {
    print("In foo")
    bar()
    return(NULL)
}

bar <- function() {
    print("In bar")
    dash()
    return(NULL)
}

dash <- function() {
    print("In dash")
    browser()
    return(NULL)
}

foo()
```

Comment: I've been avoiding `browser()`. It's absurd to modify one's source files while debugging them. Regardless, how does that help with debugging closures?

Comment: @Vrokipal In your last example `bar()` will be defined during run time of `foo()` and it only exists during runtime of `foo()` and only in its scope. So maybe absurd is not so absurd.

Comment: @Aleph Yes, of course it doesn't exist yet. Again, how does your solution address debugging closures??